# Combine the contents of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I am comfortable using cbind to combine two vectors as such:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c("Y", "Y", "N", "N")
cbind(a, b)
```

and getting this:

```
      a   b  
[1,] "1" "Y"
[2,] "2" "Y"
[3,] "3" "N"
[4,] "4" "N"
```

But what I can't seem to find in the documentation is a way to combine the contents of `a` and `b`, so I can get:

```
      a     
[1,] "1Y" 
[2,] "2Y" 
[3,] "3N" 
[4,] "4N"
```

What is the best way to combine the contents of 2 vectors in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `paste`.

```
paste(1:4, letters[1:4])
# [1] "1 a" "2 b" "3 c" "4 d"
paste(1:4, letters[1:4], sep="") # same as paste0
# [1] "1a" "2b" "3c" "4d"
```

If you require it to be a column matrix and not a vector, you can then coerce to matrix.

```
matrix(paste(1:4, letters[1:4], sep=""))
#      [,1]
# [1,] "1a"
# [2,] "2b"
# [3,] "3c"
# [4,] "4d"
```

For further information, see `?paste`.